# Upload a file, MemoryStream vs FileInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, memorystream, fileinfo

I have to generate some files in my asp.net web application and send it to the client.
So I made a method who work with a memory stream and send the buffer to the http response.

It is working fine but I just read another code and the guy is using a fileInfo. So if I understand correctly FileInfo is a "real" file written on the server disk.

So what is the best choice? (if there's one) What are questions I have to ask me? Is it about the size of the file?

Note that I don't care about storing the file, once he is send I don't have to have it on the server.

Comment: FileInfo `aids in the creation of FileStream objects` so.. MemoryStream vs FileStream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) is only a pointer to a file already stored on a file system. If you want to access its contents you need to use a stream. So in your case if you don't want to save the file on the server you could use a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) and write it to the response. A Stream is also a pointer to some data. A MemoryStream is a pointer to a data stored in memory. So you will need to first load this data in memory.

A better way is to directly write to the `Response` object in chunks. This way you don't need to load the whole file contents in memory. But this will depend on how you are generating the file.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the [`FileUpload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) class? If all you need is the stream to the file, you can then use [`FileUpload.FileContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filecontent.aspx) property. But in the future, if you did care about it, and want to save it, it's simply [`FileUpload.SaveAs({path on server})`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx).

This way you can use the same class/control regardless of your implementation needs now, or in the future.

More info on the relevant MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx).